# add new line ' ' automatic to option of selecte

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, jquery

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Questions>
  <Question>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Text>aaa</Text>
  </Question>
</Questions>

function PopupUserRegist() {
 $.ajax({   
    type: "GET",
url: "Administrator/Questions.xml",
    success: parseXml
 });



function parseXml(xml)
{        
  $(xml).find("Question").each(function()
  { 
    var value=$(this).find('Text').text()
      $('#<%=sctQuestion.ClientID %>').
      append($("<option></option>").
      attr("value",value).
      text(value)); 
    });
 }

 $("#div_userregist").dialog("open");

}
```

HTML MainMaterPage.aspx

```
<select runat="server" id="sctQuestion">
<option></option>
```

This code Automatically Add New Line Content '   ' to option of `<select>`

select:row 1==`' '`

select:row 2==`'aaaa'`

how remove `' '`
 in first row select

`$("#<%=sctQuestion.ClientID %>").removeOption(0);`

error say:.removeOption(0);  is not a function

Comment: how remove ' ' from first row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select runat="server" id="sctQuestion">
```

for this 
         `<option></option>` add ' ' to select

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the list before you start appending:

```
 $('#<%=sctQuestion.ClientID %>').empty()
```

Comment: no. if remove <option></option> say error that append is not defined

Comment: @user634146 You are right. It has to be done differently. See my modified answer